# Understanding proof of Existence of square roots of positive real number.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, real-numbers

In the proof given here https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Existence_of_Square_Roots_of_Positive_Real_Number,
in an attempt to contradict $u^2 = r$, in the first case where $u^2 > r$ they have stated $0\lt\frac{1}{n}\lt\frac{u^2 - r}{2u}$ while in the second case where $u^2 < r$ they have stated $0\lt\frac{1}{n}\le\frac{u^2 - r}{4u}$. I am trying to understand the inequality signs on the upper bounds of $\frac{1}{n}$ as to why they have used $\le$ in the second case and $\lt$ in the first one?

Comment: There's no particular benefit in making the inequality non-strict, especially when the condition $0 < \frac{1}{n} \le \frac{u^2 - r}{4u}$ is accompanied by the additional (strict) condition $\frac{1}{n} < 2u$. This leads to the desired result of $(u + 1/n)^2 < r$. That said, this proof commits a serious error, in that it concludes $u + 1/n \in S$, when this number will not generally rational. Take the whole proof with a large grain of salt.

Comment: @TheoBendit Couple of mistakes, that's all. Shouldn't take much to fix it.

Comment: Thanks @TheoBendit